# How to read structs from a separate file into a single array using fread in C

Tags: c, arrays, struct, fread

I'm currently trying to write a program to read a bin file, using a preconstructed struct in a separate header file. I am able to get the program to write out directly what is in the Bin file using the struct, but I'm lost when it comes to directing that into an array. Whenever I attempt to insert an array to read into first, the program stops working and crashes.

Here is my current code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "project7.h"

int main() {
    struct game_structure Game;
    FILE * fp;
    fp = fopen("games.bin", "rb");

    while (1) {
        fread(&Game, sizeof(Game), 1, fp);
        if (feof(fp)) {
            break;
        }

        printf("\nTitle: %s", Game.gameName);
        printf("\nGenre/Game Type: %s", Game.gameType);
        printf("\nDeveloper: %s", Game.developer);
        printf("\nReview Score: %d", Game.reviewScore);
        printf("\nGame Length: %.2lf", Game.gameLength);
        printf("\nAmount Sold: %d", Game.amountSold);
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\nFinished\n");

    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

And here is what is in the custom header file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct game_structure
{
    char gameName[20]; // Name of the game
    char gameType[30]; // Video game or physical game? Activity or boardgame?
    char developer[30]; // Who created the game?
    int reviewScore; //What was the review score? Let's just use 1-5 for simplicity.
    double gameLength; /* How many hours does it take to complete? Use 
    whole numbers for hours, followed by period and then the minutes. I.E. 
    6.30 means 6 hours and 30 minutes. */

    int amountSold; //How many copies of the game have been sold?
} Game;
```

Essentially, even if it is more of a hassle to write it into an array first, that is what I need to do. How can I go about writing multiple possible struct inputs into an array? Each part of the struct has 5 different inputs, so I need to be able to store all of them into an array and then call upon each different input with the correct inputs to the other parts of the struct.

Comment: You need to show the code you've attempted to use to read into an array.  There are many, many possible ways to get it wrong, and it is impossible for us to guess which one(s) you've chosen.  Note that the header as shown doesn't compile because you've spread single-line comments over multiple lines.  Please create an MCVE ([MCVE]) which is an honest attempt at loading the data into an array.

Comment: Note that the custom header does not have include guards (such as `#ifndef PROJECT7_H_INCLUDED` and `#define PROJECT7_H_INCLUDED` at the top, and `#endif /* PROJECT7_H_INCLUDED */` at the bottom), and does not need to include either `<stdio.h>` or `<stdlib.h>` for the code to be usable.